# Hide textView cursor

Tags: ios, textview

Is there any way to hide the cursor without resigning the keyboard?

```
textView.editable=YES;
```

hides the cursor but also resigns the keyboard.

Any suggestions?

Comment: *Welcome to Stack Overflow. Spend some time to learn SO markdown syntax  please.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this May be helpfull

```
[[UITextView appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Thanks Cheers .. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just subclass the UITextView and in your .m file put this code -

```
- (CGRect)caretRectForPosition:(UITextPosition *)position
{
    return CGRectZero;
}
```

and in storyboard give your textview outlet class name as your Subclass instead of "UITextView".

Just this..It will work 100%. try it.